# Storing primary keys of objects in Redis and then querying them in Postgres through Django

Tags: django, postgresql, redis

All suggestions, advice and insight on this matter is extremely appreciated. I require you're brutal honesty as well. If you think what I'm currently doing in terms of design is really stupid, TELL ME! because I'm a self-taught back-end software engineer and I can use all the advice I can get.

I use Django, Redis & PostgreSQL. Let's say for example I have a User, Post & Location model.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        media_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        related_location = models.ForeignKey('Location')

class Location(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
```

Great, now that's out of the way, let's say users wanted to see all the posts tagged at a certain location. This location has an ID of 1812. The normal way of doing this is to make a simple query and return posts where the related_location has an ID of 1812. I would paginate the results so that user will see 10 objects at a time. If they want to see more, they need to make another request.

I used to do things this way, until recently I've had the scare of databases growing potentially large and queries becoming really slow. So I decided to create indexes on Redis for each Location object. For example, let's say posts 7, 33, 18, 12, 89, 56500, 34000, 30 we're all tagged at location 1812. I would create a Redis List called 'location:1812' and in that list, it would contain the IDs of all the posts that we're tagged there, in this case it would: redis_list = [7, 33, 18, 12, 89, 56500, 34000, 30].

I would then take this list and query against it:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(pk__in = redis_list).order_by('-pk')
```

Is this a smart thing to do? Immediately I began to think of the pros and cons of the approach. For one, queries to the DB would be faster since I already know which objects I need to grab. However, in terms of design, is it worth it? For something like unique location objects, that table in postgres alone can grow infinitely large (over a billion unique rows). Storing a unique list for each location object in Redis can be costly (memory running out).

So it all comes down to this. Is the DB good enough, or should I continue doing what I am doing?

Comment: Do you need transactions? I mean, if redis is badly updated, you will look for bad objects in PostGreSQL, is it important for your case? Also did you consider changing PostGreSQL tables, indexes or you simply can't (because of legacy etc)? One table per location for instance?

Comment: @zenbeni I update Redis at the same time the DB is updated. The two are always in sync. And I thought about having a table for each location, but I think that would be overkill. Legacy is one of the reasons why making this change would be hard. Do you think it's worth storing the primary keys in Redis and query Postgres with those keys or should I just rely on the DB itself and query for those objects based on the location_id? ie. queryset = Post.objects.filter(related_location_id = 1812).order_by('-pk')?

Comment: I suggest putting aside Redis and using good old fashioned Django caching.  It's well supported, very flexible, and is designed for exactly your use case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/